# SharePoint REST API - odata $expand is not working on a specific site

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, odata

I am using SharePoint API to get list items. One of the fields is User Picker.
The query looks like this:

`/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Actions')/items?$select=AssignedTo/Id,AssignedTo/UserName&$expand=AssignedTo`

I have two sites (same tenant), with exactly the same list. When I execute this query on the first site, it succeeds and returns the results (list of items, with AssignedTo expanded). But when I run this query on the second site, it fails with the following message:

`Cannot get value for projected field AssignedTo_x005f_UserName.`

What could be the reason?

Please note that this applies not only to this list, but to other lists on the site as well. $expand on User lookup simply does not want to work there for some reason.

Comment: Can you please check and let us know, what is the [internal name](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html) name of your Assigned To field in 2nd list?

Comment: It is "AssignedTo" in both cases. If I give incorrect name, I get a different error: The query to field 'AssignedTo' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains AssignedTo

Comment: @GaneshSanap The whole thing looks lie there is some issue with profile service, or some other related service.. Obvious reasons like invalid syntax and invalid field name I've already checked. Would like to get a recommendation what non-trivial things can be checked..

Comment: Do you have the same values in AssignedTo field in both lists? Could it be that there is a problem with a user account that one of the items in second list contains in AssignedTo field?

Comment: Yes, the values are the same.. the fact is I can't see the difference at all.. thinking about exporting the site as template and comparing the XMLs.

Comment: Can you create a simple MS Flow/Power Automate with a [Get items] and a [Compose] actions to see if it can get AssignTo field values from the 2nd list? MS Flow can retrieve expanded values for **Person or Group** type column.

Comment: Does /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Actions')/items?$select=AssignedTo/*&$expand=AssignedTo work?

Comment: How were the lists created? Are these subsites in the same site collection or are these different site collections?

Comment: @Choggo /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Actions')/items?$select=AssignedTo/*&$expand=AssignedTo this query gives syntax error (on both sites, looks like "*" is invalid for expand): The query to field 'AssignedTo' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains AssignedTo.

Comment: @DerekGusoff first two identical blank site collections ("group site") were created using admin, then the same pnp script executed to create the lists. May it be that the site collection NAME starts with a number?